# How to change id of parent and all its child elements in clone.Node

Tags: javascript, parent-child, clonenode

How to change id of parent and all its child elements in clone.Node?

I need to change id of parent and child, but only parent's id gets changed.

```
<div id="parent" style="border:1px solid black;background-color:pink">
  <div id="child1" style="color:red;">A r element</div>
  <div id="child2" style="color:green;">A g element</div>
  <div id="child3" style="color:blue;">A b element</div>
</div>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var elmnt = document.getElementById("parent");
  var elmntid = document.getElementById("parent").id;
  var cln = elmnt.cloneNode(true);
  cln.id = elementid + "copy";
  document.body.appendChild(cln);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to append something to all the cloned elements' IDs, you can do something like this:

```js
document.querySelector('#button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  const clone = document.querySelector('#parent').cloneNode(true);
  const elementsThatHaveId = [...clone.querySelectorAll('[id]')];
  if (clone.matches('[id]')) {
    elementsThatHaveId.push(clone);
  }
  elementsThatHaveId.forEach((e) => {
    e.id += 'Copy';
  });
  document.body.append(clone);
});
```

```html
<div id="parent" style="border:1px solid black;background-color:pink">
  <div id="child1" style="color:red;">A r element</div>
  <div id="child2" style="color:green;">A g element</div>
  <div id="child3" style="color:blue;">A b element</div>
</div>

<button id="button">Try it</button>
```

What this does is to select all elements of the cloned node that have an `id` attribute (`clone.querySelectorAll('[id]')`), add the node itself to the result array if it has an `id` attribute as well and then go through the list to modify all those elements' IDs

Answer (score 1):

Try this... make a function to change the id, and loop through the child elements and pass every child to itself function.

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  document.getElementById("clone").addEventListener("click", function() {
    var clone = document.getElementById("a").cloneNode(true);
    idC(clone);
    document.getElementById("t").appendChild(clone);
  });
});

function idC(elm) {
  elm.id = "copy" + elm.id;
  for (let i = 0; i < elm.childElementCount; i++) {
    idC(elm.children[i]);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="a">
  <div id="b">
    div
    <input value="input" id="c">
  </div>
  <div id="b2">
    label
    <div id="c2">
      div
      <input value="input" id="c3">
    </div>
  </div>
  <input value="input" id="b3">
</div>
<div id="t">
  <input id="clone" value="clone" type="button">
</div>
```